# How to install FFMPEG in PHP to encode video

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I want to know how this FFMPEG to integrate in php. I want to encode video. I got this link earlier to refer

http://youtubeclone.wordpress.com/2007/05/26/how-to-convertencode-files-to-flv-using-ffmpeg-php/

but dont know where to point this

$ffmpegPath = "/path/to/ffmpeg";
$flvtool2Path = "/path/to/flvtool2";

here we have to give the path "/path/to/ffmpeg", "/path/to/flvtool2". I am little bit confused what to do or how to integrate ffmpeg, flvtool2 in php

Comment: I am using wamp in my local machine and have had a linux server to upload the stuff after completion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
exec("ffmpeg -i /tmp/orig.mov /tmp/output.mp4");
```

You don't need those $ffmpegPath variables on a properly configured system. Rather than employing pseudo security, you should escape input and output filenames using `escapeshellarg()`.

Conversion options are available in the ffmpeg manual or man page. Google will know more about your flvtool2.